# How to vertically center text inside flex element

Tags: css, flexbox, center, vertical-alignment

I have an element, which can contain 1-3 another elements. Let's say it's like this:

```
<div id="elem1">
   <div class="inner_element">aaaa</div>
   <div class="inner_element">bbbb</div>
</div>
```

The inner elements have to be positioned in column direction. I need their text to be centered vertically and horizontally.

I have my CSS like this:

```
#elem1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.inner_element {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 100%;
}
```

The text is aligned horizontally, but I cannot find any combination of flex attributes, which will align the text vertically as well. Please, can anybody advice, how to center the text inside the inner elements vertically?

Comment: If you meant that the `.inner_element` should share their parent's height equal, and their text should align centered, do like this: https://jsfiddle.net/apuaov5g/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the flex items along the main axis (in your case column/vertically), add `justify-content: center;` to the container (and erase the flex settings from the children):

```css
#elem1 {
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner_element {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1">
  <div class="inner_element">aaaa</div>
  <div class="inner_element">bbbb</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to give your wrapper a fixed height so the inner elements calculate the center with reference to that.